# Intuition on norm of quotient space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

**Theorem.** Let $(X,\| \cdot \|$) be a normed space. Then
$$ p(x+U) = \inf_{z \in U} \|z-x \|$$
defines a semi-norm on $X/U$ with $p(x+U) \leq \|x \|$.

a) If $U$ is closed, then $p$ is a norm.

b) If $U$ is closed and $X$ a Banach space, then $(X/U, p)$ is a Banach space.

I'd like some *intuition* on a), b). (Not a proof!) What is a deeper reason that closedness fixes the semi-norm and that Banach spaces induce Banach spaces?

I suppose amongst the most important applications is to take $U$ to be some kernel (even of a semi-norm, as seen in $L^p$ spaces). Perhaps it's easier to argue intuitively here and then to take some natural generalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $p$ is always a seminorm on the quotient and if it is not a norm there is $y=q(x)$ (where $q$ is the quotient map) such that $p(y)=0$ but $y\neq 0$. The latter condition means that $x$ isn't in $U$ but the former means that one can approximate $x$ arbitrarily well by elements of $U$.

(2) Completeness of quotients is much deeper than (1). One can deduce it from a version of the open mapping theorem (a linear continuous map between Banach space is surjective and open if the *closure* of the image of the unit ball of the domain contains some ball in the range, see, e.g., Rudin's book on functional analysis) applied to $j\circ q$ where $j$ is the embedding of $X/U$ into its completion.

Comment: (1) Excellent! (2) Oh wow, amazing. I didn't know that it can be deduced from the open mapping theorem. Do you know where I can find such a proof? (It doesn't seem to be in Rudin, though I only skimmed it quickly.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember my source for this proof of (2).

Comment: No problems, I‘ll try to find it myself.

Comment: It is in Rudin's book "real and complex analysis", but maybe worded a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

(1) will become clear in the proof once you prove well-definedness.

(2) should be at least intuitively true. It just says that Banach spaces behave properly to quotients. This is to be expected from a useful norm.

Comment: I'm not so sure. For me (1) can of course be seen in the proof but that is merely a somewhat technical argument/computation to verify its validity for me, not intuition. As for (2): Why do Banach spaces behave properly to quotients? Why is this a useful norm and what exactly makes it behave properly? That's what I'm seeking, deeper meanings of those.

Comment: It is a useful norm precisely because it behaves good w.r.t. quotients. It is a canonical norm on your quotient space

Comment: And the closedness is needed to make the thing well defined. It doesn't work without. Not sure if there is more to say. Maybe because closed => complete, you can think of it as: if I divide out a Banach subspace, I get another Banach space.

Comment: Hm, alright, I agree, closedness is needed for well-definedness. I like to think it as this: The semi-norm measures the distance of affine subspaces $x+U$ to $U$. If affine subspaces $x+U$ come arbitrarily close to $U$, then also all points on the subspaces. By closedness $x+U$ converges to $U$; that is: If $p(x+U) = 0$, then $x+U = 0$. This is of course just a reformulation of the proof (as you mentioned). For me, the geometric wording makes it more intuitive.

Comment: About the Banach space in (2). You're right, we need closedness to talk about it because otherwise we won't (easily) get a normed space. Now still, I'm interested in why dividing out Banach spaces behaves so well. I have a hunch that it might have to do with complements $X = U \oplus V$ where $V \cong X/U$. This is true in many cases and for me another way to think about quotients. If one chooses $V$ correctly, then one can probably make the norms as similar as possible. And if $V$ is closed, then $V$ is Banach. So I'd love to make this idea clearer.

Comment: I don't think that thinking of quotients like complements is beneficial. I'd rather think of it as the original space with extra relations.

Comment: And why is that? In Functional Analysis a great deal of complements is related to quotient spaces - as is in linear algebra. I‘m also not sure why you‘d say „extra relations“, clearly the quotient space holds less information than the original space, as parts are modded out.

Comment: Complements are the wrong way to think about it: Consider the group quotient $(R, \cdot)/(R^+\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$. It is isomorphic to $Z_2$. What would thinking about the complement help here?

Comment: Extra relations just mean: think you are in the original space, but there are extra relations between the elements. For example. Consider the quotient ring $R[X]$ and mod the ideal $(X)$. Thus, in the quotient ring we have $(X) = 0$. Then, you can think of the quotient ring as the original ring where you have $X=0$, and it becomes clear that $R[X]/(X) \cong R$. Sorry for the late answer btw. Completely forgot about this.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about complements in the following sense: If $V= W \oplus W'$, then $W'  \cong V/W$. In that case, your intuition with complements is justified.